# date('W') is returning strange week number

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have this code

```
$week = date('W', strtotime("2013-12-30"));
```

and $week is returning 01

How can that return 01 if we are in December? How can I fix this? As this is impacting on another part of the code where I'm trying to get the monday of each week:

```
$monday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$year}-W{$week}-1"));
```

But when I do that with that date, it's returning the monday of week 01.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working correctly.

The "week number" is sometimes counterintuitive.   See the note from "Jimmy" for the documentation of date using `W` format:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#106974

Answer (score 3):

`date("W")` returns the iso8601 week number. That date falls into the first week of the next year. This can occur when the last day(s) of December fall mid-week. This can also happen when December ends late in the week. The first couple of days of January can be considered part of the previous year.

See [Week dates in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) for a better explanation:

> If 1 January is on a Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday or Thursday, it is in week 01. If 1 January is on a Friday, Saturday or Sunday, it is in week 52 or 53 of the previous year (there is no week 00). 28 December is always in the last week of its year.